# Abstracting code from question blocks to modules

Tags: docassemble

I have a working interview (yay!), and I'm working on refactoring it. I'm trying to figure out what might be a good way to move my `code` blocks into `.py` files. In particular, I'm worried about maintaining some of the fancy things docassemble does (the particular `code` block I'm thinking about is marked `initial: True`, for example).

Would the idea be to convert whatever your `code` blocks are doing into functions, and then assign the variables `docassemble` is looking for in a way that uses those functions? Presumably the results of those functions still need to be dealt with in `code` blocks?

Is the below roughly the right approach (code below)? I'm assuming that:

1. Trying to run `Bcode.func(A ...)` as below, if `A` was undefined, would trigger the exception necessary to cause `docassemble` to search for the question needed to set `A`?
2. Variables can be passed as set out below.
3. `returning` from functions works as set out below.

Are any / all of these assumptions correct / incorrect?

So...

If this was my `questions.yml` file:

```
---
question: A?
yesno: A
---
# code setting value of B
---
code: |
    if A:
         answer = "A"
    elif B:
         answer = "B"
    else:
         answer = "C"
---
```

**To abstract away the code**, I assume I might do something like this?

`questions.yml`:

```
---
imports:
    - Bcode
---
question: A?
yesno: A
---
initial: True
code: |
    answer = Bcode.func(A, *args_to_set_value_of_B)
---
```

`Bcode.py`:

```
---
def func(a, *args_to_set_value_of_b):

    # code computing value of b

    if a:
        return "A"
    elif b:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "C"
---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do

```
modules:
  - .Bcode
```

Then docassemble will run (in effect):

```
exec("from docassemble.yourpackage.Bcode import *", user_dict)
```

where `user_dict` is the interview answers (the namespace of Python code in your YAML file).  This will make the name `func` available in the namespace of your interview so that it can be used in `code` blocks, Mako templating, etc.

Your `initial` block will raise an exception because `Bcode` is not a name in the interview answers.

Your function `func()` will always raise an exception whenever `a` is true, because `b` is not defined in the namespace of `func()`.

Docassemble works by trapping `NameError`, `IndexError`, and `AttributeError` exceptions and then looking for a `question` or `code` block that will define whatever variable was undefined.  `NameError` exceptions work with any type of variable, but `IndexError` and `AttributeError` exceptions only work on instances of `DAObject` or subclasses thereof.

When you move code into module files, it is important to make sure that the code in the module file does not raise `NameError` exceptions, because those will cause confusion; docassemble will try to define the variable in the interview answer namespace, but this will never fix the problem inside the module because that name will be undefined inside the module no matter what.  However, it is safe for code in a module file to raise `IndexError` and `AttributeError` errors on `DAObject` variables that have been passed from the interview namespace to the module namespace, because when docassemble defines those variables in the interview answer namespace, the definitions will be available inside the module as well.

Comment: Ohhhhhhkay. So I guess I sort of see the difference between using `modules:` and `import:`. Presumably if I used `import:` there would be no error trying to run `Bcode.func()`... changed question in that regard.

Good to know about `NameError`.

Comment: Using `imports` with `.Bcode` block would run `import docassemble.mypackage.Bcode`, which will add the name `docassemble` to your namespace, not `Bcode`, so you would have to write `docassemble.mypackage.Bcode()`.

Comment: Agh. I'll get there eventually, lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid moving code into a module that doesn't have a clear interface. It's totally appropriate to have code blocks in the YAML that contain interview logic. I keep modules for reusable, abstracted code.